# IFileOperation::MoveItems not working on namespace extension root

Tags: windows, explorer, windows-shell

So I have this rooted (on a specific file type) namespace extension that supports drag-and-dropping files into it. I use IFileOperation to handle file operations.

Moving/Copying a file that comes from outside the NSE into a sub-folder works. Copying a file into the namespace root works. However, I can't get to move a file into the root. It just does. Not. Work. My extension is never inquired for a ITransferDestination, although it is for other use cases.

Have you ever been in this situation ?

Notes:

- I'm building the extension on top of Bjarke Viksoe's great [TarFolder](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/tarfolder.htm) codebase.
- The error I'm getting (through the standard Explorer dialog) is "The file is already in use"
- the copy engine seems to end up deciding I'm trying to move a file from the regular file system to the regular file system. The above error is the one returned by a call to `MoveFileEx`, from what I could gather by tracing in there.
- the PIDLs look correct, and IFileOperation::CopyItems works for the same inputs anyway.
- I'd like to stick with IFileOperation, as it provides the most natural integration

Answer (score 1):

Try contacting Bjarke directly, he may have some insight as to what may be going on.

His email:

bjarke@viksoe.dk

I personally haven't worked with his frameworks before, sorry I can't be of any more help than this.

Comment: Heh. Indeed. An investigation is in the works with him, I'll post whatever we can find.